# How to map related data with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm trying to map three entity models into one viewmodel using AutoMapper. The final output should be a recursive category tree with products in the categories. The category tree is working, but the `Products`-property of the viewmodel is `null`. My query is returning categories and products, so I'm thinking that the mapping doesn't know how to map the products to the viewmodel.

My entity models:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentCategory))]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    // Nav.props:
    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; }
    public List<ProductInCategory> ProductInCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsProductCategoryFrontPage { get; set; }
    // Nav.props.
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    // Nav.prop:
    public List<ProductInCategory> InCategories { get; set; }
}
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public string ProductCountInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return Products != null && Products.Any() ? Products.Count().ToString() : "0";
        }
    }

    public ViewModelProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelProductCategory> Children { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried this mapping (maps categories, but no products):

```
CreateMap<ProductCategory, ViewModelProductCategory>();
CreateMap<ViewModelProductCategory, ProductCategory>();
```

I have tried this mapping (maps categories, but no products):

```
CreateMap<ProductCategory, ViewModelProductCategory>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.ParentId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ParentId))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.SortOrder, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SortOrder))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Products, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductInCategory));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want to skip the junction (link) entity in the view model.

To do that, first create a mapping from `Product` to `ViewModelProduct` and then define a mapping from `ProductCategory.ProductInCategory` to `ViewModelProductCategory.Products` using projection converting `List<ProductInCategory>` to `IEnumerable<Product>`. AutoMapper will take care converting `IEnumerable<Product>` to `List<ViewModelProduct>` the same way as if you were querying `Products`:

```
CreateMap<Product, ViewModelProduct>();

CreateMap<ProductCategory, ViewModelProductCategory>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Products, opt => opt.MapFrom(
        src => src.ProductInCategory.Select(pc => pc.Product)));
```